# How to fetch frames from a video without losing some of them?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I created an AVI file from 30 PNG images, 15 frames/second:

```
ffmpeg -i %02d.png -r 15 video.avi
```

But when I tried to get the images back from the AVI:

```
ffmpeg -i src.avi %02d.png
```

I only got 19 images, instead 30! I also tried these two:

```
ffmpeg -i src.avi -r 15 %02d.png
ffmpeg -r 15 -i src.avi %02d.png
```

both with same result. Needless to say that there are missing frames (jumps from 4th to 6th, for instance). How come and how do I solve it?

Output for first command (`ffmpeg -i %02d.png -r 15 video.avi`):

```
ffmpeg version N-50314-gf6fff8e Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 25 2013 21:57:41 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 17.103 / 52. 17.103
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.100 / 54. 63.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 41.100 /  3. 41.100
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from '%02d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:01.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 713x386 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 713:386], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, avi, to 'video.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf54.63.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 713x386 [SAR 1:1 DAR 713:386], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 15 tbn, 15 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> mpeg4)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   19 fps=0.0 q=2.0 Lsize=      46kB time=00:00:01.26 bitrate= 297.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=11    

video:40kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 15.248175%
```

Output for second command (`ffmpeg -i video.avi %02d.png`):

```
ffmpeg version N-50314-gf6fff8e Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 25 2013 21:57:41 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 17.103 / 52. 17.103
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.100 / 54. 63.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 41.100 /  3. 41.100
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, avi, from 'video.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 297 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 713x386 [SAR 1:1 DAR 713:386], 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 15 tbc
Output #0, image2, to '%02d.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 713x386 [SAR 1:1 DAR 713:386], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 15 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 -> png)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   19 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:01.26 bitrate=N/A    

video:129kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.016665%
```

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - I edited my question with the outputs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Same frame rate for input and output

Use `-framerate` as an input option to set the frame rate for image inputs. Example:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 15 -i %02d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

The default `-framerate 25` will be applied if you omit this option. If you only supply an input frame rate, as shown in the example above, then ffmpeg will inherit that same frame rate for the output without dropping or duplicating frames.

`-pix_fmt yuv420p` is recommended to be added for compatibility when outputting H.264 video.

#### Different frame rates for input and output

If you want to vary the input frame rate and output frame rate then add the `-r` output option. This may be useful if you want the input to have a low frame rate, but have a more standard output frame rate for compatibility:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i input_%03d.png -r 24 -pix_fmt youv420p output.mp4
```

The above example will display one input frame per second, but the output frames will be duplicated so the output will actually play at 24 frames per second.